# Backend Play Framework, what for frontend?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, frontend

I want to use as a backend the play framework. However, I have only experience with `primefaces && richfaces && jsf2.0`. What would you choose as a good frontend framework, especially for rapid prototyping?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: What's wrong with the scala templating?

Comment: Scala, Japid... or AngularJS/similar if you don't want to depend on backend templating.

Comment: @Kayaman thx for your answer! I do not think that scala templating is bad. However, with primefaces for example I have included many components which I do not have to write by myself, therefore I save a lot of time. Hence, I am looking for a libary which is as feature rich and is extremely well integrated into play...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a long discussion about this on the play framework mailing list recently that you might find interesting: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/IKdOowvRH0s/discussion